# flutter click tab hide under container

Tags: flutter, containers, tabbar

I am a beginner of flutter.

I am developing a flutter app.

this is my flutter app screen.
I want to hide the marked part as blue when I tap the bookmark tab bar.
I have tried several methods, but I could not achieve my goal.
I really need your helps.

[image]

I attached my whole code.

```
import 'package:botanic_flutter/login_page.dart';
import 'package:botanic_flutter/main.dart';
import 'package:botanic_flutter/root_page.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:botanic_flutter/custom_color_scheme.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';



class AccountPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String userUid;

  AccountPage(this.userUid);

  @override
  _AccountPageState createState() => _AccountPageState();
}

class _AccountPageState extends State<AccountPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  final FirebaseAuth _Auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;


  FirebaseUser _currentUser;

  TabController _controller;

  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController =  ScrollController();
    _controller = TabController(length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        bottom: true,
        child: DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: NestedScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, isScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                    _detailedBody()
                  ]),
                ),
                SliverPersistentHeader(
                  pinned: true,
                  delegate: TabBarDelegate(
                    Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TabBar(
                          unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.greyColor,
                          labelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                          controller: _controller,
                          indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                          tabs: [
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                              child: Tab(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.home,
                                ),
                                text: 'PLANTS',
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 80,
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                              child: Tab(
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.bookmark_border,
                                ),
                                text: 'BOOKMARK',
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                        _bottomButtons(tabindi)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: TabBarView(
                controller: _controller,
                children: <Widget>[
                  GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                    itemCount: notes.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                      child: Image.network(notes[index],
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  GridView.builder(
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 1.0),
                    itemCount: notes.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                      child: Image.network(notes[index],
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _detailedBody() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 3 / 4,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
              image: NetworkImage(
                  'http://www.korea.kr/newsWeb/resources/attaches/2017.08/03/3737_cp.jpg'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          transform: Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, -41.0, 0.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 90.0,
                    height: 90.0,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 82.0,
                    height: 82.0,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                            'https://steemitimages.com/DQmS1gGYmG3vL6PKh46A2r6MHxieVETW7kQ9QLo7tdV5FV2/IMG_1426.JPG')),
                  ),
                  Container(
                      width: 90.0,
                      height: 90.0,
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 28.0,
                            height: 28.0,
                            child: FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: null,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              //child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 25.0,
                            height: 25.0,
                            child: FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: null,
                              backgroundColor:
                                  Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                              child: Icon(Icons.add),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ))
                ],
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
              Text(
                'nickname',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24.0),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
              Text(
                'introduce',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15.0),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0)),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  signOutWithGoogle().then((_) {
                    Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/'));
                  });
                },
                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                child: Text('로그아웃'),
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0)),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        '0',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '식물수',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        '0',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '팔로워',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        '0',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '팔로잉',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  var tabindi = 0;

  Widget _bottomButtons(tabindi) {
    print(tabindi);
    return tabindi == 0
        ? Container(
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 15.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.clear_all,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/3*1.4,
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    isExpanded: true,
                    items: <String>['Foo', 'Bar'].map((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (_) {},
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 5.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.mode_edit,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 1.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 30,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4.5,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.mainColor,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                    boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                          offset: Offset(2, 4),
                          blurRadius: 5,
                          spreadRadius: 2)
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "+식물등록",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () => {
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        :
        Container();

  }


  List<String> notes = [
    'https://steemitimages.com/DQmS1gGYmG3vL6PKh46A2r6MHxieVETW7kQ9QLo7tdV5FV2/IMG_1426.JPG',
    'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/BKvyuWq6b5apNOqvSw3VxB-QhezYHAoX1AptJdWPl-Ktq-Efm2gotbeXFtFlkr_ZPZmpEHc2BsKTC9oFQgzBimKsf5oRtTqOGdlO3MTfwiOT54E5m-lCtt6ANOMzmhNsYMGRp9Pg1NzjwMRUWNoWX0oJEFcnFvjOj2Rr4LtZpkXyiQFO',
    'https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R720x0.q80/?scode=mtistory2&fname=http%3A%2F%2Fcfile28.uf.tistory.com%2Fimage%2F2343174F58DBC14C2ECB8B',
    'https://steemitimages.com/DQmS1gGYmG3vL6PKh46A2r6MHxieVETW7kQ9QLo7tdV5FV2/IMG_1426.JPG',
    'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/BKvyuWq6b5apNOqvSw3VxB-QhezYHAoX1AptJdWPl-Ktq-Efm2gotbeXFtFlkr_ZPZmpEHc2BsKTC9oFQgzBimKsf5oRtTqOGdlO3MTfwiOT54E5m-lCtt6ANOMzmhNsYMGRp9Pg1NzjwMRUWNoWX0oJEFcnFvjOj2Rr4LtZpkXyiQFO',
    'https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R720x0.q80/?scode=mtistory2&fname=http%3A%2F%2Fcfile28.uf.tistory.com%2Fimage%2F2343174F58DBC14C2ECB8B',
    'https://steemitimages.com/DQmS1gGYmG3vL6PKh46A2r6MHxieVETW7kQ9QLo7tdV5FV2/IMG_1426.JPG',
    'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/BKvyuWq6b5apNOqvSw3VxB-QhezYHAoX1AptJdWPl-Ktq-Efm2gotbeXFtFlkr_ZPZmpEHc2BsKTC9oFQgzBimKsf5oRtTqOGdlO3MTfwiOT54E5m-lCtt6ANOMzmhNsYMGRp9Pg1NzjwMRUWNoWX0oJEFcnFvjOj2Rr4LtZpkXyiQFO',
    'https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R720x0.q80/?scode=mtistory2&fname=http%3A%2F%2Fcfile28.uf.tistory.com%2Fimage%2F2343174F58DBC14C2ECB8B',
  ];

  Future<void> signOutWithGoogle() async {
    // Sign out with firebase
    await _Auth.signOut();
    // Sign out with google
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
  }
}


class TabBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  TabBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final Column _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => 130.0;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => 130.0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset,
      bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      color: Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
      height: 130.0,
      child: _tabBar
    );
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant TabBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I am looking forward your answers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Offstage` widget

```
          Offstage(
            offstage: _controller.index == 1,
            child: _bottomButtons(tabindi)
          ),
```

Update when tap `TabBar`

```
 TabBar(onTap: (_) => setState((){}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, the `_bottomBottons` is not instantly hidden when I tab the BOOKMARK tab. The `_bottomBottons` is hidden when I click the tabbar view.

Comment: Call `setState` when changed.

Comment: Where can I add the `setState` function?

Comment: TabBar(onTap: (_)=>  setState((){}));

Comment: Do you mean like that? `TabBar(
                          onTap:(_)=> setState((){}),
                          unselectedLabelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.greyColor,`